# How to add or subtract n days from UTCTime?

Tags: haskell, time

How can I add/subtract n days from a value of type `UTCTime` from the `time` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Data.Time

addDaysUtcTime :: UTCTime -> Integer -> UTCTime
addDaysUtcTime t x = addUTCTime (nominalDay * (fromIntegral x)) t
```

or

```
import Data.Time

addDaysUtcTime :: UTCTime -> Integer -> UTCTime
addDaysUtcTime t x = t { utctDay = (addDays x (utctDay t))}
```

Comment: `60*60*24` or `nominalDay` would be suitable values of type `NominalDiffTime`.

Comment: Thanks! I assume though that `NominalDiffTime` will not take account of things like DST though, so maybe this isn't ideal?

Comment: DST doesn't affect UTC times. Perhaps you're thinking of leap seconds? I don't know the answer there, but I usually find that when I care about it, the `time` package's documentation is very explicit about what happens.

Comment: Whoops, completely forgot it's related to UTC. I guess I was thinking about the timezoned type `Localtime`.